# Finding matches between 30,000+ data sets

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm, graph-algorithm

For simplicity sake, lets use a case example of 3 colors with corresponding numbers (there is actually 30,000+ different 'colors' and 254 different 'numbers' in real life though)

Red   - 0, 1, 2, 3, 10, 15

Green - 0, 2, 3, 20

Blue  - 2, 10, 11, 12

I want to find the matches between them (rgb, rg, rb), as well as keep a tally of the number of #s shared between the set:

rgb = 1

rg = 2

rb = 2

Finally it'll need to determine a ratio of the number of #s shared compared to the number of distinct #s in the set.

rgb = 1/9 (since it has a distinct: 0, 1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 15, 20)

rg = 2/7 (0, 1, 2, 3, 10, 15, 20)

rb = 2/8 (0, 1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 15)

---

So the total output would be

match | # of matches | % |

rgb   |    1  |  1/9

rg    |  2   |   2/7

rb     | 2   |  2/8

---

The algorithm I was able to come up w/is you have each color in a table and map the numbers associated with it (aka red (table Name), 0, 1, 2, 3, 10, 15 (data)). Then take the color with the most 'numbers' and compare it to every other color's hours, find matches.  Once done with that color you can 100% ignore it and move onto the next color and do comparisons with n-1.

Take the example:

1) Select red

2) Does any other color share 0

3) Does any other color share 1

....etc

4) Select blue
5) Does any other color minus red share .....

I know that there has to be a more efficient way to do this, any suggestions?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What are red,green blue? Tables? columns? Files?

Comment: Do a 3 way outer join on values and then gather aggregate data from that result depending on which columns are null

Comment: red, green, blue are their just to show an example.  What I actually have is a bunch of alarm conditions (30,000+), and corresponding 'hours' (a value from 0-254).  I want to match them all together.

So in terms of a database I could store it as:

Database is color, Table is red, Data (1 column): 0, 1, 2, 3, 10, 15

An example data set would be: afaGenericAlarm - 0, 20, 34, 50, 100, 250.

Each alarm can only have a number once.

Comment: @MattWhipple I wish i could do an outer join, but your talking about 30,000 way outer join.  Also the data is dynamic so that number will be increasing.

Comment: I'm talking about 3 way join, if you have 30,000 tables then you have a schema issue.  If you do have 3 tables then I'd certainly try the join before prematurely optimizing it.

Comment: @MattWhipple The issue is that there are 30,000+ different 'colors' which can have corresponding numbers in the range of 0-253. If you know a better way to store them w/o creating a table w/253 columns and 30,000+ rows or 254 tables for each number, and their corresponding enteries.

Comment: @ColinBookman could the colors be represented as 256bit integers? (Or 4x64bit integers, or 8x32bit etc)? Then you might be able to use the bitwise AND and OR for your computations.

Comment: @ColinBookman You definitely need to remodel your data, or if you want to stick with what you have then an RDBMS is not your best option.  It sounds like you're using columns as part of the data rather than field definition.  If each cell represents a unique value and the column affects that, then that should be combined into a single value in a single column, or maybe 2 columns where the 2nd acts to modify the 1st.  How to do it would depend on what you're looking to do which isn't clear.  You need to step away from the idea of tables and start over.   Relations != tables like that.

Comment: Your example does not make it much clearer. there are only 256 distinct values from 0...255. Where does the 30000 com from?

Comment: @wildplasser So using the 'color' example.  I have 30,000 different colors (red, green, blue,..etc) and 255 different numbers (0, 1, 2,....).  *I want to find the colors (30,000) with matching numbers  (254)

*Edit

Comment: @ColinBookman assuming you have 30,000 Strings which are colors each of which will have multiple values from 0-255 (byte)?  If that is the case then using a single table and self joins would get you closer to where you need to be.  Or for performance a color table with just names and ids and then the value table would have an fkey.

Comment: @MattWhipple Thanks I knew I was forgetting something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there are only 254 (or 255 if your 0-254 comment is correct), then you can express the sets of 'numbers' for each 'colour' as a 256-bit integer. Then the number of shared numbers for r and g is just the bitcount of (r and b) and the number of distinct numbers is the bitcount of (r or b), so using your example,

if R is the bit-set for red, G is the bitset for B etc:

```
match | # of matches            | %                                             |
rgb   | bitcount(R and G and B) | bitcount(R and G and B)/bitcount(R or G or B) |
rg    | bitcount(R and G)       | bitcount(R and G)/bitcount(R or G)            |
rb    | bitcount(R and B)       | bitcount(R and B)/bitcount(R or B)            |
```